# Determining the type of magnet used in a hand-crank torchlight

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetics, electromagnetic, diy

I'm trying to design a DIY dynamo that recharges a 5V battery used to power some sensors. However, I am having some trouble with deciding on the arrangement of coils and magnets. Currently, I am trying to adopt the arrangement seen in a hand crank torchlight where a magnet (encased in the grey cylinder below the small gear) is spun above a coil of wire:

[image: Hand crank torchlight]

However, I'm having some trouble deciding on whether I should use a axially magnetised or diametrically magnetised ring magnet as I am unable to determine what kind of ring magnet the torchlight uses. I tried using another magnet to identify the poles of the ring magnet but it seems that the ring magnet has 4 alternating north and south poles on the same surface? Furthermore, either the north or south poles are much smaller than their counterparts for some reason.

[image: Types of ring magnets]

From an online link the field lines look like this so I'm guessing the rate of change in flux density is the same for both and using whichever does not really matter?

**Is this true or will there be little to no current induced for 1 of the arrangements and which?** I am really limited by budget and am planning to purchase the strongest magnet with no replacements at all.

[image: Field lines for ring magnets]

Edit: made the question clearer

Comment: Why not compare cost to energy density?

Comment: I think there's not really much comparison to be made. I just need to determine which type of disc magnet should be bought, if the magnet type can't be determined (i still have no clue from searching the net), then the bar magnet design will be used even though it has a higher cost to energy density ratio.

It's my first time working on a electricity and magnetism project and I honestly have no clue about what works and what doesn't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true or will there be little to no current induced for 1 of the arrangements and which?

The diametrically or radially magnetized magnet will work if the magnet is spun around the axis and the axis of the coils is perpendicular to the magnet axis. The axially magnetized magnet must be spun around a line that is perpendicular to the axis.

Mechanical losses in the gears is a very important consideration. Increasing the number of magnetic poles and thus the number of coils will allow for a lower speed and less speed increase with gears. However coil winding is more difficult and "wasted" space between coils reduces the effectiveness, so you need a compromise. Three-phase is better than single phase, but requires more coils. For the best design in terms of how much energy you can manually produce you need to consider effort, comfortable cranking speed and operating time. Your are likely to find that the "best" design is the most expensive and difficult to make.

Answer (score 1):

Key to getting any efficiency from your generator is to pass as much of the magnetic flux through iron rather than through air.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Electrical World 360](https://electricalworld360.com/ac-generator-alternator-construction-and-working/).*

Note in this three-phase generator how the north and south poles are connected right through so there is no air gap between them. Note how there is a magnetic circuit between each coil pole around the outside of the case. The result is that the only air losses are in the very small gaps between the rotor and the stator.

I suggest that you read up a lot more before spending your money. You might find that a small motor would be better as all the mechanical work is done. Note also the very high gearing used in the device in your photo. This is essential as the output voltage will depend on the rotational speed.